# How can I copy files with names containing spaces and UNICODE, when using a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, file, scripting

I have a list of files that I'm trying to copy and move (using cp and mv) in a bash shell script.  The problem that I'm running into, is that I can't get either command to recognize a huge number of files, seemingly because the filenames contain spaces and/or unicode characters.  I couldn't find any switches to decode/re-encode these characters.  Instead, for example, if I copy "file name.xml", I get "*.xml" and a script error that the file wasn't found for my result.  Does anyone know settings or commands that will deal with these files?

EDIT(adding current code):
When I run:

MacBookPro:Desktop$ ./script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
dateVar=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
mkdir /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar
cd /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/SMSdrop
for i in *.xml
do
cp $i /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar/$dateVar-$i
done
```

I get the message:

usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-pvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-pvX] source_file ... target_directory

...when it hits the "cp" command.  There's actually more to the script, that processes the copied files further.  With a "regular" file name e.g. 'file.xml', everything works fine.  It's only files with spaces, or Unicode characters, where I have problems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problems with spaces indicates that insufficient quoting has been done. The following is incorrect:

```
someprogram $file
```

The correct version is as follows:

```
someprogram "$file"
```

Comment: Thank you!  Changing the code to:
cp "$i" /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar/"$dateVar"-"$i"
...worked perfectly!

Comment: or even: `cp "$i" "/Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar/$dateVar-$i"`. In a shell script, *always* quote variables unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

watch out for code errors when $i is null!
This can be the result of fatal rm -Rf errors!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are easier ways than dealing with shell quoting. In your case I would use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`. The null character termination allows you to easily manipulate strings with spaces (i.e lists of filenames).

For your example, code would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
dateVar=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
mkdir /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar
cd /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/SMSdrop
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml' -print0 | \
xargs -0 -I {} cp {} /Volumes/Documents/SMSarchive/$dateVar/$dateVar-{}
```