# Copy files form multiple subdirectories to a different directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have multiple sub directories in which i have multiple csv file. I wanted to copy all the files alone into a different directory.

I am able to find or list the files using wildcards

`find  -name '*.csv'`
`ls /**/'*.csv'`

The challenge is all the directory names and file names are having spaces and so am unable to achieve the expected result.

Comment: A correctly constructed command has no problem with spaces. We can't know what you did so we can't tell you where you went wrong. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: `find . -name '*.csv' -exec cp {} dest/ \;` will work portably, but is somewhat inefficient. `find . -name '*.csv' -exec cp -t dest {} +` is better, but requires GNU `cp`. Both of these will obviously overwrite files at the destination if you find several CSV files in different directories with the same name.

Comment: @tripleee `find . -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c 'cp -- "$@" dest/' -- {} +` ?

Comment: Yeah, that too; but again, we have a lot of existing duplicates with solutions. As they have not followed up with clarifications, I guess let's just close as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550791/how-can-i-copy-files-with-names-containing-spaces-and-unicode-when-using-a-shel

Comment: Or perhaps simply [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy files with names containing spaces and UNICODE, when using a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550791/how-can-i-copy-files-with-names-containing-spaces-and-unicode-when-using-a-shel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec cp {} Folder \;
```

In that command, `Folder` is your `different directory`.
And You have to create that directory before you run this command

**Before you run this command**

- `cd` to  your main directory or Home directory.
- Create the directory that you want to copy all csv files (`mkdir Folder`)

Comment: If you think this question is an obvious duplicate of an existing question, please don't answer it. Once you earn enough reputation, you will be able to leave a comment to point out the duplicate target.

Comment: The advice to `cd` somewhere is dubious. If they wanted to find files in their current working directory, the `find` command then needs to be adapted. A much better solution is to learn how to pass relative or absolute file names when required, and give up the superstition that `cd` is somehow necessary (though it can certainly be convenient). See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)